# Tkinter: Issue with Multiple Montiors

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I'm running Tkinter on a machine that has 3 monitors.  Is there a way to specify which monitor (& the location on that monitor) to display my GUI?

Answer (score 3):

The `.geometry()` method of the root (or any Toplevel) window is your interface to its size and position.  Call it with no parameters to get a geometry string; you can then call the method with that string to set the window to the same place on the screen.  For example, I get `'200x200+5+28'` for a small window on my main monitor, `'200x200+2592+414'` after moving it to the monitor on the right.  (This is on Mac OS X, conceivably it works differently on other platforms.)

Comment: just to confirm it works in the same way on windows (tested xp, 7 and 10)